# How is looking into a million element set faster than checking a single value?

Tags: python, performance, set

So I was testing with a code that checked if numbers followed the [Collatz Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Collatz_conjecture) from 1 to 1 million, and make different versions of them, hopefully each new one faster than the last one.

So this is the fastest version I archieved:

```
def v5():  # Avg t: 1.104s

min_n = 1
max_n = 1_000_000
global_steps_list = {1, 2, 4}

for n in range(min_n, max_n):
    steps_list = set()

    while True:
        if n in global_steps_list:
            global_steps_list.update(steps_list)
            break

        elif n % 2 == 0:
            n /= 2
        else:
            n = 1 + (n * 3)

        steps_list.add(n)
```

And this works fast but I noticed that there was no need to check if the n in the while loop had already fallen into a collatz path, so I decided to change that line from `if n in global_steps_list:` which is a very large set to what seemed more reasonable like a `if n == 4:` which at some point all numbers get eventually(although n=1 has to do an extra unecessary step. But the time instead of dropping went from **1.104s** to **31s**! which was unexpected.

So I reasoned it had to do with sets being the greatest thing in existence and changed it to `if n in {4}` which I think should be more reasonable as we're checking into a set that is 1 entry long instead of 1x10^6. But the time was around **37s**! Therefore I stated the set above, before the main for loop to `l = {4}` and checked if `n in l:` which got me a time of around **~42 seconds**. I don't know how to improve this part of the code, but more importantly I'm wondering if there is anyone that knows why this happens? Maybe it has to do with the set being called before and therefore being in cache or some dark magic like that? Idk.

Also please don't suggest ways of improving this code outside this line as I'm doing this to learn from it, not to actually get a fast code for any practical reason.

EDIT: It should also be mentioned that the tests weren't a one-time fluke as I ran them 10 times one after the other to get the average and I did that multiple times.

Comment: But your code has to do more loop iterations to get to 4, doesn't it? Also, the set membership test performance doesn't really depend on size. It just calculates the hash of the value and checks in the according hash bucket.

Comment: Yeah, I just figured that out now. :)

Answer (score 1):

By short-circuiting when you reach a number known-to-satisfy the conjecture, you're effectively applying the pattern known as memoization.  Whether memoizing is a performance win depends on the relative costs of a "hit" (being able to short-circuit) relative to a "miss" and the probability of a hit vs. a miss.

As your set gets larger, the chance of a hit increases while the cost of a checking for membership in the set doesn't increase that quickly (this depends somewhat on the algorithm used to implement the set: for a set which is growing, I suspect python implements it as a binary tree by hash, which would tend to take a constant amount longer for every time it doubles in size).  Since it doesn't take that long to reach a number in the set compared to the time to iterate to 4, this is a massive win.

Answer (score -1):

I just found out what was the problem. It hadn't to do with types or whatever. It's just that if I just check if it gets to 4, then there's no point for the `global_step_list` as remebering numbers that fell into the 4,2,1 cycle are not used.